# How to create a generic autocomplete helper for my domain entities in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, autocomplete

In one of my asp.net mvc projects, I want to provide autocomplete with general data source url and typed autocomplete for my domain entities. I am looking for asp.net mvc helper

Comment: Post some of your work so people can help.. by the way, this can be achieved using any auto-complete API using ajax and database in back-end which contain all the domain entities.. Also, using asp.net mvc, this can be done in same manner in the defined scope..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When i started my new project in ASP.NET MVC, I had requirement to provide a input control like auto complete for many number of domain entities (department, employee, product, categories etc.) and for general purpose. I just wanted to use auto completes instead of dropdown list

This is useful when there is a requirement to provide auto suggestion kind of data entry to end user

Two helpers with various overloads in terms of having attributes, auto complete type, is required, on select call back and source URL. One helper used for strongly type view and other one for view with no model binding

How it works

Helper creates two html input elements one type of hidden and other type of text. Id and name of hidden would be the developer give name of autocomplete or model propertyname. Id and name for the textbox would be the name of hidden _AutoComplete (ex: hidden name is ProductID, textbox name is ProductID_Auto Complete). Selected text shown in text box and selected value goes to hidden control. On submission of the current form both the values from hidden and text will be submited to server.

If we specify the source url to the control, the it gets the data from specified url. In other case if we specify the type of auto complete the data loads from a predefined url.

A JavaScript callback function can be specify to execute after select an item from autocomplete

Client side required validation can be added by using parameter IsRequired = true

Test requirements
•Visual Studio 2013
•ASP.NET MVC 5
•jquery-1.10.2
•jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min AutoComplete plugin

Using the code

Code blocks consists of following resources

•Department, Employee ( c# classes domain entities of this attached source )

•AutocompleteHelper ( c# statick class to define the helpers)

•TestAutoCompleteController ( c# MVC controller class to return data to auto completes request)

•CustomAutoComplete script ( Jquery script to handle auto complete request and responses from client)

•View ( Index.cshtml to design the sample view)

First define an Enum to specify the type of data to load in terms of entity names

AutoComplete Helper

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;

namespace AutoCompleteHelper_MVC.Extensions
{

    public enum AutoCompleteType
    {
        None,
        Department,
        Employee,
    }

    public static class AutoCompleteHelper
    {

        public static MvcHtmlString Autocomplete(this HtmlHelper helper, string name, string value, string text, string actionUrl, bool? isRequired = false, IDictionary<string, object> viewhtmlAttributes = null, string onselectfunction = "")
        {
            return GetAutocompleteString(helper, name, value, text, AutoCompleteType.None, actionUrl, isRequired, viewhtmlAttributes, onselectfunction: onselectfunction);
        }
        public static MvcHtmlString Autocomplete(this HtmlHelper helper, string name, string value, string text, AutoCompleteType autoCompleteType, bool? isRequired = false, IDictionary<string, object> viewhtmlAttributes = null, string onselectfunction = "")
        {
            return GetAutocompleteString(helper, name, value, text, autoCompleteType, "", isRequired: isRequired, viewhtmlAttributes: viewhtmlAttributes, onselectfunction: onselectfunction);
        }
        private static MvcHtmlString GetAutocompleteString(HtmlHelper helper, string name, string value, string text, AutoCompleteType autoCompleteType, string actionUrl = "", bool? isRequired = false, IDictionary<string, object> viewhtmlAttributes = null, string onselectfunction = "")
        {
            return GetHelperString(helper, name, value, text, autoCompleteType, actionUrl, isRequired, viewhtmlAttributes, onselectfunction);
        }
        public static MvcHtmlString AutocompleteFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, string DisplayProperty, string actionUrl, bool? isRequired = false, IDictionary<string, object> viewhtmlAttributes = null, string onselectfunction = "")
        {
            return GetAutocompleteForString(helper, expression, DisplayProperty, AutoCompleteType.None, actionUrl, isRequired, viewhtmlAttributes, onselectfunction: onselectfunction);
        }
        public static MvcHtmlString AutocompleteFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, string DisplayProperty, AutoCompleteType autoCompleteType, bool? isRequired = false, IDictionary<string, object> viewhtmlAttributes = null, string onselectfunction = "")
        {
            return GetAutocompleteForString(helper, expression, DisplayProperty, autoCompleteType, "", isRequired: isRequired, viewhtmlAttributes: viewhtmlAttributes, onselectfunction: onselectfunction);
        }
        private static MvcHtmlString GetAutocompleteForString<TModel, TValue>(HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, string DisplayText, AutoCompleteType autoCompleteType, string actionUrl = "", bool? isRequired = false, IDictionary<string, object> viewhtmlAttributes = null, string onselectfunction = "")
        {
            string name = ((MemberExpression)expression.Body).ToString();
            name = name.Substring(name.IndexOf('.') + 1);
            Func<TModel, TValue> method = expression.Compile();
            object value = null;
            if (helper.ViewData.Model != null)
                value = method((TModel)helper.ViewData.Model);
            return GetHelperString(helper, name, (value != null ? value.ToString() : ""), DisplayText, autoCompleteType, actionUrl, isRequired, viewhtmlAttributes, onselectfunction);
        }
        private static MvcHtmlString GetHelperString(HtmlHelper helper, string name, string value, string text, AutoCompleteType autoCompleteType, string actionUrl = "", bool? isRequired = false, IDictionary<string, object> viewhtmlAttributes = null, string onselectfunction = "")
        {
            if (autoCompleteType != AutoCompleteType.None)
            {
                UrlHelper url = new UrlHelper(helper.ViewContext.RequestContext);
                string acpath = url.Content("~/TestAutoComplete/");

                if (autoCompleteType == AutoCompleteType.Department)
                    actionUrl = acpath + "GetDepartments";
                else if (autoCompleteType == AutoCompleteType.Employee)
                    actionUrl = acpath + "GetEmployees";
            }


            if (viewhtmlAttributes == null)
                viewhtmlAttributes = new Dictionary<string, object>();

            viewhtmlAttributes.Add("data-autocomplete", true);

            viewhtmlAttributes.Add("data-autocompletetype", autoCompleteType.ToString().ToLower());

            viewhtmlAttributes.Add("data-sourceurl", actionUrl);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(onselectfunction))
            {
                viewhtmlAttributes.Add("data-selectfunction", onselectfunction);
            }


            if (isRequired.HasValue && isRequired.Value)
            {
                viewhtmlAttributes.Add("data-val", "true");
                viewhtmlAttributes.Add("data-val-required", name + " is required");
            }

            viewhtmlAttributes.Add("data-valuetarget", name);

            MvcHtmlString hidden = helper.Hidden(name, value);

            MvcHtmlString textBox = helper.TextBox(name + "_AutoComplete", text, viewhtmlAttributes);

            var builder = new StringBuilder();

            builder.AppendLine(hidden.ToHtmlString());

            builder.AppendLine(textBox.ToHtmlString());

            return new MvcHtmlString(builder.ToString());
        }


    }
}
```

Department model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace AutoCompleteHelper_MVC.Models
{
    public class Department
    {
        public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
        public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
        public static List<Department> TotalDepartments
        {
            get
            {
                return new List<Department>{
                                            new Department{DepartmentID=1,DepartmentName="Accounts"},
                                            new Department{DepartmentID=2,DepartmentName="Advertisement"},
                                            new Department{DepartmentID=3,DepartmentName="Sales"},
                                            new Department{DepartmentID=4,DepartmentName="Shipment"},
                                            new Department{DepartmentID=5,DepartmentName="Production"},
                                            new Department{DepartmentID=6,DepartmentName="Marketing"}
                                            };
            }
        }
        public static List<Department> GetDepartmentsLikeName(string namestring)
        {
            var x=TotalDepartments.Where<Department>(d=>d.DepartmentName.ToLower().StartsWith(namestring.ToLower()));
            return x.ToList();

        }
    }
}
```

Employee Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace AutoCompleteHelper_MVC.Models
{
    public class Employee
    {
        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
        public static List<Employee> TotalEmployees
        {
            get
            {
                return new List<Employee>{
                                            new Employee{EmployeeID=1,EmployeeName="Addison",DepartmentID=1},
                                            new Employee{EmployeeID=2,EmployeeName="Ashwin",DepartmentID=1},
                                            new Employee{EmployeeID=3,EmployeeName="Alden",DepartmentID=1},
                                            new Employee{EmployeeID=4,EmployeeName="Anthony",DepartmentID=6},
                                            new Employee{EmployeeID=5,EmployeeName="Bailee",DepartmentID=5},
                                            new Employee{EmployeeID=6,EmployeeName="Baileigh",DepartmentID=4},
                                            new Employee{EmployeeID=7,EmployeeName="Banjamin",DepartmentID=2},
                                            new Employee{EmployeeID=8,EmployeeName="Cadan",DepartmentID=3},
                                            new Employee{EmployeeID=9,EmployeeName="Cadimhe",DepartmentID=2},
                                            new Employee{EmployeeID=10,EmployeeName="Carissa",DepartmentID=1},
                                            new Employee{EmployeeID=11,EmployeeName="Ceara",DepartmentID=2},
                                            new Employee{EmployeeID=12,EmployeeName="Cecilia",DepartmentID=1}
                                            };
            }
        }
        public int DepartmentID { get; set; }

        public static List<Employee> GetEmployeesLikeName(string namestring)
        {
            var x = TotalEmployees.Where<Employee>(d => d.EmployeeName.ToLower().StartsWith(namestring.ToLower()));
            return x.ToList();

        }
    }
}
```

Test Controller

```
using AutoCompleteHelper_MVC.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace AutoCompleteHelper_MVC.Controllers
{

    public class TestAutoCompleteController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /AutoComplete/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var empObj = new Employee { EmployeeID = 1, EmployeeName = "Michale" };
            return View(empObj);
        }

        public ActionResult GetEmployees(string searchHint)
        {
            return Json(Employee.GetEmployeesLikeName(searchHint),JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        // GET: /AutoComplete/
        public ActionResult GetDepartments(string searchHint)
        {
            return Json(Department.GetDepartmentsLikeName(searchHint), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        // GET: /AutoComplete/
        public ActionResult GetGeneralItems(string searchHint)
        {
            return Json(Employee.GetEmployeesLikeName(searchHint), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
}
```

Custom AutoComplete javascript

```
//attached autocomplete widget to all the autocomplete controls
$(document).ready(function () {
    BindAutoComplete();
});
function BindAutoComplete() {

    $('[data-autocomplete]').each(function (index, element) {
        var sourceurl = $(element).attr('data-sourceurl');
        var autocompletetype = $(element).attr('data-autocompletetype');
        $(element).autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: sourceurl,
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { searchHint: request.term },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            if (autocompletetype == 'none') {
                                return {
                                    label: item.EmployeeName,
                                    value: item.EmployeeName,
                                    selectedValue: item.EmployeeID
                                };
                            }
                            else if (autocompletetype == 'department') {
                                return {
                                    label: item.DepartmentName,
                                    value: item.DepartmentName,
                                    selectedValue: item.DepartmentID

                                };//
                            }
                            else if (autocompletetype == 'employee') {
                                return {
                                    label: item.EmployeeName,
                                    value: item.EmployeeName,
                                    selectedValue: item.EmployeeID

                                };//
                            }
                        }));
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                    },
                });
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                var valuetarget = $(this).attr('data-valuetarget');
                $("input:hidden[name='" + valuetarget + "']").val(ui.item.selectedValue);

                var selectfunc = $(this).attr('data-selectfunction');
                if (selectfunc != null && selectfunc.length > 0) {
                    window[selectfunc](event, ui);
                }
            },
            change: function (event, ui) {
                var valuetarget = $(this).attr('data-valuetarget');
                $("input:hidden[name='" + valuetarget + "']").val('');
            },
        });
    });
}
```